# no overload method takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, wcf, distributed-computing

Hi I have a WCF service and within it I have this method

```
void SendData(int pumpNo, List<String> pumpInfo);
```

however when I try to pass an int and a list into it, I get an error saying

> Error 1   No overload for method 'SendData' takes 2 arguments

This is how I passed data to it in the WCF client

```
sendpumpdata.SendData(pumpID, pumpData);
```

ok so at the top I create an instance of the WCF service by doing...

```
ServiceReference1.iCommClient sendpumpdata = new Pumps.ServiceReference1.iCommClient();
```

also in my service.cs I have created the method defined in the IService.cs

Comment: Did you add this method directly to service ? or you defined it in the service contract (interface) and then implemented in the service class ?

Comment: Can you show more code, like how what `sendpumpdata` and `pumpData` are?

Comment: Are you using web references? If so, you might need to update those first.

Answer (score 1):

A WCF web service leverages client generated code (i.e. a proxy) to communicate with the server. In your situation, even though the server code has two parameters, your client generated code must be out of date.

If you're using a Web Reference or a Service Reference just right click and Update Reference. If you're using a static WSDL then navigate to the WSDL hosted locally for the WCF service and save it to disk and then overwrite the one in your project.

Comment: My guess is also for an outdated proxy!